# Using javascript to display different pigeon images based on multiple selection options

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I am trying to create a page where, with dropdown boxes, you can select different appearance attributes for a pigeon and it will diplay an image of whichever breed/colour/marking combination you have selected... A bit like one of those 2D 'character creators' where you can select different faces, hats, etc. which are all applied as various .png layers to a variety of base images.

Each pigeon breed will have a different base image (i.e. different body shape), then will have unique colours/markings applied as various semi-transparent layers.

At the moment I have two breeds - 'Homer' and 'Fantail'. Each of these can come in two base colours - 'blue' or 'red' and each colour can either have the 'bar' markings (in either blue or red, depending on base colour) or be 'barless' (plain).

I am not great at coding... At the moment, I have it so that I can select breed, base colour and markings, and it WILL display pigeon images (hooray) however I am having trouble getting it to only allow options based on my previous selections (e.g. not allow me to select 'red bar' marking if the selected base colour is 'blue')

I have tried using a javascript 'if' clause to the effect of: 'if selected colour is 'red', when I select marking option 'bar', display a 'red bar pigeon' (not a blue bar pigeon). But I couldn't get it to work - I just can't figure out how to make it reference the previous selections while deciding which image to display.

Here is everything I have so far:

```
   <label for="breed">Breed:</label>

<select name="breed" id="breed">
      <option value="homer" onclick="document.getElementById('Pigeon').src='./birds/basem.png'">Homer</option>
      <option value="fantail" onclick="document.getElementById('Pigeon').src='./birds/basef.png'">Fantail</option>

</select>

 <label for="base">Base colour:</label>

<select name="base" id="base">
      <option value="blue" onclick="document.getElementById('Pigeon').src='./birds/barlessblue.png'">Blue</option>
      <option value="red" onclick="document.getElementById('Pigeon').src='./birds/barlessred.png'">Red</option>
      <option value="albino" onclick="document.getElementById('Pigeon').src='./birds/purewhite.png'">Albino</option>
</select>

 <label for="markings">Markings:</label>
   
 <select name="markings" id="markings">

  <option onclick="document.getElementById('Pigeon').src='./birds/barlessblue.png'">Barless</option>
  <option onclick="document.getElementById('Pigeon').src='./birds/barlessred.png'">Barless</option> <option onclick="document.getElementById('Pigeon').src='./birds/bluebar.png'">Bar</option>
 <option onclick="document.getElementById('Pigeon').src='./birds/redbar.png'">Bar</option>
</select>


<center><img id="Pigeon" src="./birds/basem.png"></center>
</center>
```

As you can see from the image below, all options for all marking/colour combos are coming up in the dropdown, which is not ideal! One version of the 'barless' option displays the red variant. I want it so that:
a. There is only one 'bar' option available to me
b. When I have selected 'blue' in the previous dropdown, and select 'bar' in the third dropdow, it will definitely show the blue bar pigeon image.

It seems like such a simple thing, but it is totally beyond me! I am having the same issue with breed/colour. I would like to add a lot more options, but I need to get this straight first.

Thank you so much if you can help!

[Image of pigeon builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ota1U.png)

Comment: You should not be using click handlers on the option elements here to begin with. Use `change` handlers on the select fields instead, to call a function. Inside that function, read the current values of _all_ select fields, and assemble the correct image URL to use from those.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, but I'm afraid I don't understand a lot of it. I only know HTML and basic CSS, enough to make a static webpage with a 1990's aethetic. Javascript is totally new to me, but I am going to look up the things you've mentioned and see if I can work it out.